# how to create an angular datepicker directive that uses ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an angular directive for my jQuery UI datepicker. The problem is that the directive doesn't update the input's ng-model when a date is selected. Any idea why?

http://jsbin.com/ufoqan/1/edit

Answer (score 32, accepted):

AngularJS actually provides a special controller for interacting with `ngModel` that you can use inside your directives; just add `require: 'ngModel'` to your directive definition.

This gives you a fourth paramter to your `link` function, which is the controller you asked for in `require`--in this case, an instance [of `ngModelController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController). It has a method called `$setViewValue` you can use to set the value of the model:

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      $(el).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The beautiful thing about `ngModelController` is it automatically takes care of validation and formatting (in the case of a specific input `type`) and integration with things like `ngChange` callbacks; check out [this example](http://jsbin.com/ufoqan/6/edit): http://jsbin.com/ufoqan/6/edit

Comment: Good answer. Note , there is an exisiting jquery UI datepicker here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Reading the source code will help understand how ngModelController works

Answer (score 6):

There may be a better way, but this will work:

http://jsbin.com/ufoqan/4/edit

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      $(el).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          console.log(dateText);
          var expression = attr.ngModel + " = " + "'" + dateText + "'";
          scope.$apply(expression);
          console.log(scope.startDate);
          // how do i set this elements model property ?
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You also asked why.  The reason is that jquery happens outside the angular system.  You can find more info here under the $apply method: [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: thank you! what if i had a function call stored on my directive attribute and I wanted to invoke that. how would i do that? http://jsbin.com/ufoqan/5/edit

Comment: nvm, i think i got it, scope.$apply(attr.datepicker);

Answer (score 0):

@Michelle Tilley and @Jonah are right about linking your directive to ngModel, but why you didn't use datePicker that is pure Angular instead of jQuery?
Well, i represent [`ADMdtp`](https://github.com/AmirkabirDataMiners/ADM-dateTimePicker) module. It's pure AngularJs dateTimePicker with lots of greate options:

- completely synced with ngModel, so no need to destroy or manulay update dateTimePicker.
- advance range picker; make as many dateTimePicker as you want related together, and again no need to destroy or manualy update each dateTimePicker.
- disabing pattern; so easily you can disable any day(s) in week or month, like all weekends.
- transition on changing days. (of curse you can disable it in options)
- get full date details like date in UNIX format, Date format and year, month, day, hour and minute separately and ... by full-data attribute.
- ...

`<adm-dtp ng-model="date" full-data="date_full"></adm-dtp>`