# Cooperation ngMessages with datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ngMessages in my Angular project for validation forms and have got problem with using this with Datepicker. When I choose a date ng-message doesn't disappeared, as I understand ngMessages doesn't see any events. 
I've tried to use dispatchEvent('keypress' and 'keydown') with my date input for calling some ngMessages' event, but nothing is happened.
Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle? Help will be provided you as soon as we have more info

Comment: Please, look for the example http://plnkr.co/edit/l12nmBECrWhZoynUgTaO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You have painful code from jquery there, please try to use datepicker from angular. Here you have a directive that you could reuse:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Angular can live with jquery code, but that doesn't mean that they will synchronize their behaviors (events, models...etc.)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if I want use my own datepicker what should I do for ngMessages' right using. I've tried to set error object's options like valid, invalid, setValidity(required, true) and etc. by hands, but, unfortunately, nothing had happened.

Comment: The problem is that nothing work out of the angular scope, so what I would do in this situation is to create a directive and in the link function you can do $(input).datepicker() and apply everything you want, but through angular. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725755/how-to-create-an-angular-datepicker-directive-that-uses-ng-model